# Continuously update UWP UI elements using multiple threads (Windows 10 IoT Core)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I have a UWP Application running on Windows 10 IoT Core where I am continuously reading outputs from multiple sensors, and displaying them in a TextBlock.

I am currently using a DispatcherTimer for each sensor, but I wanted to see if there's a way to optimize the code by using multiple threads (Each thread would gather the data from a sensor, and then the UI thread would update the TextBlocks)

I tried to write the following code but it made things way worse

This is the timer I created for one of the sensors:

```
    private void updatePeakValue()
    {
        timerPeakValue = new System.Timers.Timer(10);
        timerPeakValue.Elapsed += PeakValue_Tick;
        timerPeakValue.Enabled = true;
        timerPeakValue.Start();
    }
```

And here is the Elapsed Event (I am using rand.next to mimic reading values from a sensor):

```
    private async void PeakValue_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
            tbPeakValue.Text = rand.Next(0, 10).ToString();
        });
    }
```

This code clogs up my UI, the TextBlock only gets updated when I move my mouse

Is there anything else I could try instead of relying on multiple DispatcherTimers?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try using a ViewModel that implements INotifyPropertyChagned. Threads update vm's Text property, you raise event on the UI thread using the same `RunAsync` code you have, and UWP decides when to update UI from binding itself

Comment: @torvin Please could you elaborate more on how I can do this? ( I am kind of new to UWP platform)

Comment: Maybe try to find a tutorial on MVVM pattern. But I'm not really sure if this approach will solve your problem or not, sorry

Comment: Are you calling `updatePeakValue` more than once?

Comment: @StephenCleary No I only called it once (after InitializeComponent)

Comment: @RalphCh97: You should only be seeing 10 updates per second, then, which the UI should be able to handle easily. Can you post a minimal repro?

Comment: In real life I am using an interval of a few milliseconds (I will edit the posted code), but the issue remains while using the code I posted (For some reason, the UI would not update until I move the mouse)

While using multiple DispatcherTimers, the issue is gone, but since I have many UI updates to do, I think it would be better to using multiple threads
Also, I will try to post a minimal repro

Comment: @StephenCleary  I'm sorry, the issue is not reproducible on the PC, it only happens on the Windows 10 IoT

Comment: @RalphCh97: A few milliseconds is completely different. It's just not possible for a UI to process that many updates. You'll need to use some kind of throttling/sampling mechanism.

Comment: Keep in mind that even at maximum update speed, the UI thread typically updates once every 16ms on a 60 FPS monitor, so firing multiple updates every 10ms is overkill. Updating every 250ms, or 4 times every second, is still faster than necessary but better for your case. Even once every 1,000 would probably be fine. Depending on your IoT device you might also be using a WARP based renderer so GUI updates will be far more costly, (alongside running on slower hardware), than on desktop. There's no point updating the UI faster than a human can read.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake Okay so I understand that a single UI thread can handle getting the data and update multiple UI elements (let's say every 100ms or 200ms) and still be fine?
So there would be no need to use multiple threads for this task. Am I correct?